# Access one line of a group by in python

Tags: python

I have the following code:
df.groupby('Type').count()

Now I want to access only one output of type (Type = Bike) and not all the different types - How is this possible?

Comment: What have you tried / researched already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df.groupby('Type')` will give you a grouper object which you can do the following:

```
grouped = df.groupby('Type')
grouped.get_group('Bike')
```

see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html?highlight=group%20py#splitting-an-object-into-groups